# RunTime permission alert dialog is appearing on lockscreen

Tags: android

I am building an application which on launch asks for permissions like storage ,what is happening is, when i lock the device when permission alert dialog is on display and unlock my phone again the alert dialog appears on the lock screen it wont go until i press accept or deny 
it is behaving like this in **android 8** and above ,on lower versions it is not appearing.

Comment: I don't think that you can do something about it

Comment: i have observed that android system apps which require permission behaves the same ,in this scenario.

Comment: did anybody find solution for this ?